# Google Maps Pinpoint Display

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

My friend has a website named as http://jobifly.com .Now the issue is that when you enter the site you will see Google maps on the navigation panel and that shows the jobs which are available, but its Pin-pointing them one by one, can't it show all of them together?

Awaiting Response..

Regards,

Zain Sohail

Comment: Please post the code (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you are asking about, not just a link to your site. Certainly looks like the behavior you are asking about is the behavior that was coded.  Change the code to change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the page is that all the locations will be gecoded when the page loads. To avoid the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT this will  be done with a delay.

To show them together you must wait until all locations have been geocoded.

So your friend may either:

- use the current geocoding-strategy and initialize the map when all addresses have been geocoded(I don't think that it is an option for your friend)
- or store the LatLng's somewhere when they have been geocoded, so he can use them directly without a delay (Note: this is only permitted for up to 30 days)

It's also possible to use a FusionTable to store these data, the geocoding would be done automatically there.

Another option to be able to store the LatLng's permanent: give the users that offer a job a map where they can select the location manually by clicking on the map, the returned LatLng may be stored without restrictions.